# Is there a command or a "git log" option to retrieve comments/discussion logged for a merge request?

Tags: gitlab, git-log

We have a GITlab(8.14) running for collaboration within the company.
I am working on a python script to collect information about merge requests being raised by developers across projects. I can very easily isolate the merge requests using 'git log'
`git log --merges`

However, I haven't been able to locate the correct command or option to retrieve all the discussion/comments taking place in the Merge Request.

Comment: Does my solution below help you?

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution 1: use Gitlab Log System

Have you thought to use the Gitlab Log System instead of using a Git command?

> It contains information about all performed requests.... Also you can see all
>   SQL request that have been performed and how much time it took.

Please take a look here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/logs.html

So in your Python script of collecting information, you can use queries like that:

```
SELECT <things> FROM "merge_requests"  WHERE <condition>
```

## Solution 2: use Gitlab API

Another way is to directly request Gitlab API to get a list of all notes for a single merge request.

> Notes are comments on snippets, issues or merge requests.

like this:

```
GET /projects/:id/merge_requests/:merge_request_id/notes
```

The complete API reference for merge request notes is [available here.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/notes.html#list-all-merge-request-notes)

Does this help you?

Comment: @priyank Use the API solution.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. Looking at the docs I am sure I will be able to cook up a script now.